# Excel : Substract Character Sets

Tags: excel, excel-2010, excel-2007

We have two Columns A and B containing Industry codes and Excluded Industry code.
We need a third column C subtracting A and B.

Is There any formula to achieve this?

```
Industry                                   |Excluded  | Output
:------------------------------------------|:---------|:------
A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U  | P,L,K,L  | ?OUTPUT
------------------------------------------ |----------|------
A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U  | P,L,K,L  | ?OUTPUT
```

Comment: Are you looking for formula or some vba solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following User Defined Function:

```
Public Function Remove(s1 As String, s2 As String) As String
    Dim s As String
    ary = Split(s2, ",")
    s = Replace(Replace(s1, " ", Chr(1)), ",", " ")

    For Each a In ary
        s = Replace(s, a, "")
    Next a

    s = Application.WorksheetFunction.Trim(s)
    Remove = Replace(Replace(s, " ", ","), Chr(1), " ")
End Function
```

[image]

User Defined Functions (UDFs) are very easy to install and use:

1. ALT-F11  brings up the VBE window
2. ALT-I
   ALT-M opens a fresh module
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you save the workbook, the UDF will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the UDF:

1. bring up the VBE window as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To use the UDF from Excel:

=remove(A1,B1)

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

and for specifics on UDFs, see:

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/WritingFunctionsInVBA.aspx

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**